# GNUCash, MySQL and Azure

Tags: mysql, azure, gnucash

I am trying to configure GNUCash to talk to a MySQL database on Azure.  I have created the database and successfully restored a backup of data from my local MySQL installation.

However, when I try to connect to the cloud instance from GNUCash, I keep getting the error "GNUCash could not complete a critical test for the presence of a bug in the "libdbi" library. This may be caused by a permissions misconfiguration of your SQL database. Please see https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=645216 for more information.".  This points to a post which does not shed much light on the issue.  I have tried granting all permissions possible to MySQL database, but to no avail.

Does anyone have any experience of using GNUCash with a cloud hosted MySQL database?

Answer (score 0):

I make it work with ClearDB MySQL app that you can find in the Azure market!

It is free if you do not need lot of ressources.

Here's the link : https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/fr/marketplace/apps/SuccessBricksInc.ClearDBMySQLDatabase/?utm_source